# Как сделать реинциализацию функции?

Tags: jquery, yii2

У меня динамическое добавление изображений на своём js. 
Как сделать реиницализацию функции https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-file-kit/blob/master/src/widget/assets/js/upload-kit.js 
?
Или добавить метод как-то?

Comment: jQuery.fn.yiiUploadKit(options)

Comment: просто подключить плагин этот?

Comment: @ThisMan вам скинули то что вам нужно выполнить, чтобы реинит сделать. Ну понятно что вместо options нужно задать параметры. Их вы можете посмотреть в исходном коде (если лень разбираться) ваше странице с уже сгенерированным виджетом